# How to redirect a folder to an internal port with Nginx?

Tags: nginx, configuration, redirect, httpserver

I have Nextcloud installed at Mydomain.com using the default port 80. I'm trying to set up Nginx so that another app which runs it's own webserver gets all requests that go to Mydomain.com/webapp/ The other webserver is running on the same server listening at port 8080.

So basically, how do I configure Nginx to redirect all requests going to Mydomain.com/webapp/* to be handled by 127.0.0.1:8080 instead?

This is my current nginx-breaking https/ssl server block in: /etc/nginx/conf.d/mydomain.com/mydomain.com.conf:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/mydomain.com/crt.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/mydomain.com/key.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ALL:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:!RC4:!3DES:+HIGH:+MEDIUM;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;";

    location /webapp {
           rewrite /webapp(.*) $1 break;
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
           proxy_redirect     off;
           proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
           proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;



    include conf.d/mydomain.com.d/*.conf;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.com-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mydomain.com-error.log;
}
```

Thanks, from a first timer here!

Comment: You are missing a closing brace on your location block. Have you tested the configuration file using `nginx -t` ?